# Download portfolio on costum btn in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How it possible to create a download link button in portfolio in wordpress?
https://demo.themegrill.com/himalayas/ in this site in portfolio instead of show image link is there any way to have a link for download pdf of portfolio page?

Comment: you can add `<a href="/images/image.jpg" download>`

Comment: @vel not a specific image... dynamid PDF

Comment: Just replace the PDF url as dynamic. What you have tried?